# NPM error when i start a new project in foundation

Tags: npm

Hello I'm a newie with npm, gulp, etc. I try to make run foundation-cli.
I install globally npm, gulp, bower, node-sass, node-gyp, phantomJS, foundation-cli. And when I try to make a new project appears this errors.

```
> phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.14 install     C:\Users\ivano\npmhost\news1\node_modules\gulp-uncss\node_modules\uncss\node_modules\phridge\node_modules\phantomjs-prebuilt
> node install.js

Considering PhantomJS found at C:\Users\ivano\AppData\Roaming\npm\phantomjs.CMD
Looks like an `npm install -g` on windows; skipping installed version.
Download already available at                 C:\Users\ivano\AppData\Local\Temp\phantomjs\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows.zip
Verified checksum of previously downloaded file
Extracting zip contents
Removing C:\Users\ivano\npmhost\news1\node_modules\gulp-uncss\node_modules\uncss\node_modules\phridge\node_modules\phantomjs-prebuilt\lib\phantom
Copying extracted folder C:\Users\ivano\AppData\Local\Temp\phantomjs\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows.zip-extract-1500445503067\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows ->             C:\Users\ivano\npmhost\news1\node_modules\gulp-uncss\node_modules\uncss\node_modules\phridge\node_modules\phantomjs-prebuilt\lib\phantom
Writing location.js file
Done. Phantomjs binary available at C:\Users\ivano\npmhost\news1\node_modules\gulp-uncss\node_modules\uncss\node_modules\phridge\node_modules\phantomjs-prebuilt\lib\phantom\bin\phantomjs.exe
\
> optipng-bin@3.1.4 postinstall C:\Users\ivano\npmhost\news1\node_modules\gulp-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-optipng\node_modules\optipng-bin
    > node lib/install.js

  √ optipng pre-build test passed successfully

> jpegtran-bin@3.2.0 postinstall C:\Users\ivano\npmhost\news1\node_modules\gulp-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-jpegtran\node_modules\jpegtran-bin
```

> node lib/install.js

```
  √ jpegtran pre-build test passed successfully

> gifsicle@3.0.4 postinstall C:\Users\ivano\npmhost\news1\node_modules\gulp-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-gifsicle\node_modules\gifsicle
> node lib/install.js

  √ gifsicle pre-build test passed successfully
-
> node-sass@3.13.1 install C:\Users\ivano\npmhost\news1\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.13.1/win32-x64-57_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.13.1/win32-x64-57_binding.node":

HTTP error 404 Not Found

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
  try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.

      export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via

      npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080

> node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall C:\Users\ivano\npmhost\news1\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\ivano\npmhost\news1\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\ivano\\npmhost\\news1\\node_modules\\gulp-sass\\node_modules\\node-sass\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.6.2
gyp info using node@8.1.4 | win32 | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\ivano\npmhost\news1\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\ivano\npmhost\news1\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\ivano\npmhost\news1\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\ivano\npmhost\news1\node_modules\gulp-    sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\ivano\npmhost\news1\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\ivano\npmhost\news1\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 { Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\ivano\npmhost\news1\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\ivano\npmhost\news1\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\ivano\npmhost\news1\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\ivano\npmhost\news1\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\ivano\npmhost\news1\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\ivano\npmhost\news1\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python2\n    at     getNotFoundError (C:\\Users\\ivano\\npmhost\\news1\\node_modules\\gulp-sass\\node_modules\\node-sass\\node_modules\\node-        gyp\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n    at F (C:\\Users\\ivano\\npmhost\\news1\\node_modules\\gulp-sass\\node_modules\\node-sass\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n    at E (C:\\Users\\ivano\\npmhost\\news1\\node_modules\\gulp-sass\\node_modules\\node-sass\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n    at C:\\Users\\ivano\\npmhost\\news1\\node_modules\\gulp-sass\\node_modules\\node-sass\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n    at C:\\Users\\ivano\\npmhost\\news1\\node_modules\\gulp-sass\\node_modules\\node-sass\\node_modules\\node-    gyp\\node_modules\\which\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n    at C:\\Users\\ivano\\npmhost\\news1\\node_modules\\gulp-sass\\node_modules\\node-sass\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\node_modules\\which\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\ivano\npmhost\news1\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\ivano\npmhost\news1\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\ivano\npmhost\news1\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\ivano\npmhost\news1\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\ivano\npmhost\news1\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\ivano\npmhost\news1\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python { Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\ivano\npmhost\news1\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\ivano\npmhost\news1\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\ivano\npmhost\news1\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\ivano\npmhost\news1\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\ivano\npmhost\news1\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\ivano\npmhost\news1\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python\n    at getNotFoundError (C:\\Users\\ivano\\npmhost\\news1\\node_modules\\gulp-sass\\node_modules\\node-sass\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n    at F (C:\\Users\\ivano\\npmhost\\news1\\node_modules\\gulp-sass\\node_modules\\node-sass\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n    at E (C:\\Users\\ivano\\npmhost\\news1\\node_modules\\gulp-sass\\node_modules\\node-sass\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n    at C:\\Users\\ivano\\npmhost\\news1\\node_modules\\gulp-sass\\node_modules\\node-sass\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n    at C:\\Users\\ivano\\npmhost\\news1\\node_modules\\gulp-sass\\node_modules\\node-sass\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\node_modules\\which\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n    at C:\\Users\\ivano\\npmhost\\news1\\node_modules\\gulp-sass\\node_modules\\node-sass\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\node_modules\\which\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
gyp verb could not find "python". checking python launcher
gyp verb could not find "python". guessing location
gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Users\ivano\npmhost\news1\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ivano\npmhost\news1\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\ivano\npmhost\news1\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.15063
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\ivano\\npmhost\\news1\\node_modules\\gulp-sass\\node_modules\\node-sass\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\ivano\npmhost\news1\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v8.1.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1

There were some problems during the installation.

 ✓ New project folder created.
 ✗ Node modules not installed. Try running npm install manually.
 ✓ Bower components installed.

Once you've resolved the above issues, run foundation watch while inside the news1 folder.
```

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot download
>   "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.13.1/win32-x64-57_binding.node"

try to fixed by installing latest node-sass to project:
`npm i gulp-sass@latest --save-dev`

> Error: not found: python2

you are missing python. install it and add to PATH

this command:
`npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`
should install python and other necessary dependencies